# Self referencing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables `Towns(id, name)` and `Connections(from_id, to_id )`.
Connections aren't symetric.

How can I model this in rails, so I can use `@town.nearby_towns` ?

EDIT: `@town.nearby_towns` are towns specified by `to_id` for `@town(from_id)`

Comment: `has_many :towns, through: :connections`?

Comment: How will `nearby_town` be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
#app/models/town.rb
Class Town < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :connections, foregin_key: "from_id"
   has_many :nearby_towns, ->(ids) { where("to_id IN (?)", (ids)) }, through: :connections
end
```

This will allow you to call `@town.nearby_towns`, but I'm not sure how you're going to define which towns should be classed as "nearby"?

The way I've done it in my code is to send a series of `ids` to your association, allowing you to define which towns should be classed as "nearby"

Comment: To create a better answer, you really need to provide us with some more context

Comment: Sorry for not precise question. This one worked for me `has_many :nearby_towns, through: :connections, source: :to`